# Teamcity newman is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: postman, teamcity, newman

I am trying to run postman tests on Teamcity server. I followed this link for setup https://medium.com/@vdespa/how-to-run-postman-newman-tests-in-teamcity-9d767c7de542
Although I have installed node, npm and newman -g. When I run from TeamCity Command line build step it doesn't recognize newman command

[image: Shows that I have newman installed]

[image: Teamcity build CLI error]

As you can see in the step 2, I am just running the command $ newman --version ,but it is exited with code 0. Probably, it is not able to find where newman is installed? I also tried this $setx /M PATH %AppData%\npm but still doesn't work

Any help would be appreciated? @Valentin Despa

Comment: In Teamcity server, I also tried running running newman from the directory where my tests are located it shows 'node' is not recognized. However, I tried running the tests on my local desktop, I can run the tests from tests directory but that approach wouldn't work in TeamCity since it shouldn't be absolute path for location of the tests. But at least in my local desktop I can newman run from the absolute path where my tests are located C:\Users\user\source\repos\AutoTests>newman run APIAutoTests.postman_collection.json --environment ApiProtest.postman_environment.json

Comment: is newman file exist in %AppData%\npm directory ?

Comment: Yes, it does C:\Users\gg\AppData\Roaming\npm and I have newman windows command script and newman powershell script files exist there

Comment: Have you checked the same command in user which is used for TeamCity Service ?

Comment: That account runs the build (build agent) is a system account, so I can't login as that user. But what I ran this command as build step "npm prefix -g" and it returned following: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\npm So knowing that build agent has access to this path I installed newman at that location but I still get "newman is not recognized" error

Comment: Another solution I tried by directly initializing newman.cmd by specifying absolute path "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\npm\newman.cmd" newman -v which returns the version 4.6.0 but newman run command doesn't run e.g. "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\npm\newman.cmd" newman run -h  results in error: invalid command `newman,run`

Comment: @NirajGajjar appreciate your help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by installing newman in C:\npm folder instead of under any system folder. Also before I wasn't resetting the npm Config to default which I did this time. I am able to run my tests now.

**Detailed Steps to install nodejs, npm and newman on teamcity server**

```
Login to TeamCity Server

Download the Nodejs

Install Nodejs (C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs)

Open Command prompt as run as Administrator

type node -v (should return node version)

type npm - v (should return npm version)

type npm prefix -g (usually it defaults to user folder and returns
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm )

Note the current global prefix

Set the global prefix to by running this on cmd: npm config set prefix C:\npm

Install the needed packages by running this on cmd: npm install -g newman

Restore the prefix to the previous value by running this on cmd: npm config set prefix C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm

Open System Environment variables

Edit environment variables and make sure this added to Path: C:\npm

Also additionally you can check under user variables for user1 Path
is set to for npm: C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm

Now restart the windows server machine

After that, from the Teamcity web interface, restart the teamcity
server

You should have running newman on your teamcity server on cmd prompt as well as build steps
```